# Entity framework - Issue when using include in Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, include

I have a problem in Entity Framework using Oracle. I get the error ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000.

The particular Linq which throws the error has 5 Include. when using SQL provider it uses only MSL fiels but with Oracle it uses all fields in SSDL which exceeds 1000 columns.

Is there a way to force to use the fiels only in MSL for Oracle ?

Comment: Do you make a projection (`select new {...}`)? If not, you always should when using that many Includes.

Comment: Thanks Gert. No, i am directly using include. I will go with this if i can't find any other solution because with SQL i don't have any problem since it uses the columns only in MSL whereas with Oracle it includes all the columns in the table even if it was not mapped.